# Importing CSV file to Generate Orders in Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal commerce kickstart. I need to generate order-ids with dummy billing and shipping information. How to import csv file with order particulars? Is there any module? How to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the migrate module: https://drupal.org/project/migrate and the add-on module commerce migrate: https://drupal.org/project/commerce_migrate .

This is a coding solution, but I can't think of any other way you could do this without some coding of your own.

Comment: Ok. I'll try and let you know..

Comment: The above module didn't showing Migrate orders anywhre in drupal commerce kickstart.  I don't know why? But the links below give me solution to generate orders.

http://commerceguys.com/blog/creating-orders-drupal-commerce-api

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100563/import-orders-from-xls-csv-to-drupal-commerce

Thanks for your answer.